# Merging two lists in Python into one list; side by side

Tags: python, list, merge, python-zip

I have two lists:

years_list = [1880, 1881, 1882, 1883]

temperature_list = [23, 26, 20, 21]

I would like to merge the two lists so that both lists are in one lists but side by side. Where one list contains two lists.

I would like the output to look like this:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e90wQ.png)

How can I do that?

I have tried merging them with the '+' sign and with the zip() function but the output isn't what I want.

Comment: The output shown isn't a valid expression. Please provide the exact output you want. Also explain why `zip()` doesn't produce the output you want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using a generator inside of a function:

```
def merge_lists(list1: list, list2: list) -> list:

    # Returns items at the same index from two lists
    def _(list1, list2):
        assert len(list1) == len(list2) # Lists need to be the same length
    
        # Loop over lists
        for i in range(len(list1)):
            yield list1[i], list2[i]

    # Return list of tuples
    return [(a, b) for a, b in _(list1, list2)]

years_list = [1880, 1881, 1882, 1883]
temperature_list = [23, 26, 20, 21]

print(merge_lists(years_list, temperature_list))
# Output: [(1880, 23), (1881, 26), (1882, 20), (1883, 21)]
```

Comment: This is the same as `list(zip(years_list, temperature_list))`

Comment: This produces the same format as `zip()`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually didn't know that.